# Is there a way to make horizontal scrolling smoother

Tags: javascript, horizontal-scrolling

This fiddle is almost what I'm looking for, I got it from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollLeft). The only thing missing is that I want to make it smoother. Is there a way to do that without using jQuery or any other plugins?

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eydreeyawn/pGR3B/)

```
        var button = document.getElementById('slide');
        button.onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 100;
        };

        var back = document.getElementById('slideBack');
        back.onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft -= 100;
        };
```

Comment: I know you don't want to use plugins, but I found a vanilla JavaScript library to smooth scrolling with easing functions that doesn't use jQuery (it seems this is relatively complicated): https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll/blob/master/dist/js/smooth-scroll.js

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This could probably be optimised a fair bit, but here is a basic example of how you could do it using `setInterval` and `clearInterval`

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pGR3B/1/)**

**Update**

Here is another example of it wrapped into a function instead, bit easier to tweak the speed etc.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pGR3B/2/)

Comment: I think this is the best answer, very simple with updated fiddle too, thanks @nick!

Comment: working fine. Is there any way to add a transition effect for the elements. Like to make it look like smooth scrolling?

Answer (score 29):

**You can also use the .scrollTo method. I've modified the [jsFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/pGR3B/1/) with this javascript :**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var input = document.getElementById('content');
var scrollAmount = 0;
var scrollMin = 0
var scrollMax = input.clientWidth

document.getElementById('slide').onclick = function () {
  container.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    left: Math.max(scrollAmount += 500, scrollMax),
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
};


document.getElementById('slideBack').onclick = function () {
  container.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    left: Math.min(scrollAmount -= 500, scrollMin),
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
};
```

Comment: Update. In the latest Safari version `options` are supported

Comment: In 2021, this should be the chosen answer

Answer (score 28):

Add  `scroll-behavior: smooth;`  to the scroll element. I feel it better

Comment: For people who don't know, this is a CSS property that you need to add to the scrollable element. For example, `#scrollMe{ overflow-x: auto; scroll-behavior: smooth; }`

Comment: This does not work in Safari at the moment.

Comment: doesnt seem to work for horizontal scrolling?

Comment: Verified today, works fine for horizontal scrolling and all relevant browsers. 
fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lxkv0dtb/  , compatibility check: https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-behavior

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to keep track of the scroll position, you can use scrollBy instead of scrollTo.

```
  container.scrollBy({
    top: 0,
    left: +500,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  })
```

Comment: Wow, why's this the first I've seen this? Thanks

Comment: This is definitely the cleanest solution I have come across! thankyou

Answer (score 8):

Adding `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to `#container` will make it smooth.

Here is example on this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wtLs1pf/)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it vertically with jquery although i'm sure it can be adjusted to be done horizontally. The demo is [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/)

There's  a javascript smoothscroll on [github](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll) too added by cfernandi

Also ccheck out [iscroll.js](http://iscrolljs.com/)

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: code at http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/

Comment: Hi @Rachel thanks for these solutions but, I chose the answer of nick just because I only need a very simple solution. +1

Comment: @AdrianEnriquez always happy to help might come in handy in future :)