# Scroll Animation for Horizontal Scroll Feature

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I'm attempting to modify code given to me by a friend that will increase or decrease scroll distance within a div by clicking on a button on either side of the div. [This is where I'm at so far](https://codepen.io/weinbergmp/pen/NOVJjO) -- the code I was given to link the button to the div and action is as follows:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
  console.log("DOM loaded");
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("right-arrow");

  for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].onclick = function(e){
      console.log(`Function fired on ${this.id}`);
      var the_scroller = this.closest(".scroller-gutter");

      the_scroller.getElementsByClassName('scroller')[0].scrollLeft += 120;
    }
  }

}, false);
```

All I'd really like to do is add `{behavior: "smooth"}` somewhere to make the onClick animation less choppy and mimic the natural scrolling behavior intended, but I'm brand new to JS and have no idea what to do.

Additionally, when I rearrange the buttons within the `.scroller-gutter` div, the functionality will occasionally break. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: I can think of a number of different ways to achieve this if you're open to a refactor:  [Animate](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_animate.asp), [CSS transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp), or do a `setInterval` and increment your `scrollLeft` incrementally with ticks.  Are you determined to keep the following line?: `the_scroller.getElementsByClassName('scroller')[0].scrollLeft += 120;`

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635884/is-there-a-way-to-make-horizontal-scrolling-smoother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) function with `behavior: 'smooth'` in the options to smoothly scroll to a given point. In your case, it would look like:

```
the_scroller.getElementsByClassName('scroller')[0]
  .scrollTo({ left: the_scroller.getElementsByClassName('scroller')[0].scrollLeft + 120, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VEoYyx

You can also consider using `scrollBy()` or `scrollIntoView()`, as suggested [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)